# Tabs Jumping when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

The issue I'm having is when a tab is clicked and made active, the screen will jump to the top. I can tell it's begin targeted by the id, but I'm not too sure how to work around this.

Maybe target a different element?

```
<style type="text/css">
    /*----- Tabs -----*/
.tabs {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

    /*----- Tab Links -----*/
    /* Clearfix */
    .tab-links:after {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        content:'';
    }

    .tab-links li {
        margin:0px 5px;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
    }

        .tab-links a {
            padding:9px 15px;
            display:inline-block;
            border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
            background:#7FB5DA;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:600;
            color:#4c4c4c;
            transition:all linear 0.15s;
        }

        .tab-links a:hover {
            background:#a7cce5;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

    li.active a, li.active a:hover {
        background:#fff;
        color:#4c4c4c;
    }

    /*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
    .tab-content {
        padding:15px;
        border-radius:3px;
        box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        background:#fff;
    }

        .tab {
            display:none;
        }

        .tab.active {
            display:block;
        }
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
            var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

            // Show/Hide Tabs
            $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(600).show().siblings().hide();

            // Change/remove current tab to active
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });       
</script>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Tab #4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <p>Tab #1 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum ri.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm viewing it on chrome

Comment: I added a height to .tabs, which makes it not jump as much. I guess this will work for now. But, is there a better solution to this for future reference?

Comment: Have you tried putting preventDefault as the first line of the click function?

Comment: @user3943543 Try using `line-height` instead of `height` on a text element so it keeps its proportion, but I'm afraid this is the only way to resolve the behavior you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying when you say that "the screen will jump to the top" because the tab's being "targeted by the id," one <strike>solution</strike> alternative that apparently still has the same issue(!) is to use something other than links for the tabs themselves. For example, you can achieve the same effect using radio buttons (or checkboxes). Here's a fiddle that I very quickly threw together using your code as a basis (since I threw it together quickly, it might not work perfectly, but it'll give you the basic idea):

http://jsfiddle.net/hewa29nt/2/

Basically, your list items would look like this:

```
    <li>
        <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
        <label for="tab1">Tab #1</label>
    </li>
```

You could then use the :checked pseudo class (rather than :active on the links) for styling changes. The only problem is that this won't work on IE8 (which doesn't support :checked), so, if you care about IE8, you can use conditional comments and your original links-based code for that browser.

You can also see some discussion of options for IE8 in this sort of scenario at the end of this post, if you're interested:

http://www.ascendiv.com/pure-css-tabs-demystified-and-slightly-improved-or-pure-css-tabs-even-in-ie8/

**EDIT** At the end of that post^, there is discussion of using **:hover** instead. Doing that is one way that *really would* eliminate the jump, though your tabs will navigated by hovering rather than by clicking, and I'm not sure whether that's something you'd want.

Comment: Arrghh... I guess I should've double-checked that outside of JSFiddle before posting. Looks like it will still cause the jump (again, if I get what you're saying about jumping). At least it's an alternative to links, if that matters much... And I suppose it reveals that the jump isn't only caused by links with targets.

Comment: I'll leave the original answer up for context (and as an interesting alternative), I guess, but the edit at the end may be the solution that will get rid of the jump if you're okay with hovering rather than clicking.